# AWS CloudFormation Stack Upgrade fails with "Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement"

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I tried to update an existing jenkins stack from https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates and just modified the jenkins rpm and the AWS AMI Versions.

But on updating the stack I get this error message:

```
2019-12-17 19:14:16 UTC+0100    vpc-ci-jenkins  UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS The following resource(s) failed to update: [MasterASG].
2019-12-17 19:14:15 UTC+0100    MasterASG   UPDATE_FAILED   Received 1 FAILURE signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

Anyone an idea what might gone wrong with the update? 
There were no changes in the MasterASG section of the template.

Comment: Generic error message that could have multiple root causes. I'd start by checking the CloudWatch and CloudTrail logs and similar past issues from that repository:
https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent

Comment: I retried it today and now it worked... No idea what the difference was. I tried to search the logs but wasn't really able to find out where to find anything...
Anyway thanks for the help :)